# CSS Won't Connect with My HTML

Tags: html, css

I am doing some HTML & CSS tutorials, and I am unable to get my CSS to appear when I load my web pages.

I linked my CSS to the HTML skeleton.

Can you help me figure out the error?

Screenshot of my HTML document:

[image]

Screenshot of my CSS:

[image]

Both of the files are stored in the same folder:

[image]

If anyone could let me know where I went wrong so I could continue my process, I would appreciate it.

Comment: send the first screenshot properly. I think you have something in those only. you also have style.css out of **stylesheets** folder so don't need put **stylesheets\style.css** just put **style.css**

Answer (score 3):

The index.html and the styles.css are in the same folder, so you shouldn't point to a sub-directory for the css. Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

as both index.html and css files are in same folder, you can use

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=1.1.2">
```

here, v is version declared, so whenever you make changes in your css file, simply change this version numbers to get refresh css and changes to take effect in browser without cleaning caches..

you can also move your css file in stylesheets folder and can keep index.html structure as it is.... basically it is good practice to keep files in subfolders so we can find them easily when searching... for e.g. all .css files in stylesheet folder, all images in images or img folder, all javascripts in js folder...

by the way, what is m.m in css file, in body styling ??